# Setting z-index of ScrollView on Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, z-index

in my Xamarin.Forms app I have a simple grid - one row is a header and second one is scrollview with content of the page. In header, I have an image with negative bottom margin (half of the image needs to be over the header and other half over scrollview).

The problem is, when I scroll this scrollview, on iOS half of my image hides behind scrollview.

I made a custom renderer and on Android setting `this.TranslationZ = -100;` in `OnElementChanged` did the job - image is over scrollview when scrolling.

On iOS I tried setting `Layer.AnchorPointZ = -100;`, `Layer.Transform.Translate(0, 0, -100);`, `Layer.ZPosition = -100;` in the `OnElementChanged` and nothing worked - my image is still hiding behind scrollview.

I couldn't find any solution over the Internet so I am asking here - what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just making sure the image is added after the ScrollView in the View Hierarchy? Otherwise on iOS you call, `View.BringSubviewToFront(imageView)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS renderer , have a try with `LayoutSublayersOfLayer` override method to check whether it works , not in `OnElementChanged` to modify property of `Layer`.

```
public override void LayoutSublayersOfLayer(CALayer layer)
{
    base.LayoutSublayersOfLayer(layer);

    layer.AnchorPointZ = -100;
    layer.Transform.Translate(0, 0, -100);
    layer.ZPosition = -100;
}
```